# Ternary expression unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an unexpected token error in my ternary code expression. The error message points to the first = in the ===. What am I getting wrong here?

```
const getMyHeader = (heading, advisorTags) => {
    if (advisorTags.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Typography
          variant="h6"
          component="h6"
          style={{
            heading === 'White Advantages'
              ? 'fontSize: 16'
              : 'fontSize: 16, paddingTop: 10'
          }}
        >
          {heading}
        </Typography>
      );
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style props expect an object. What you are doing is not valid JS. You are using the [object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#creating_new_objects) to define the object, but are using statements/expressions inside it.

A simple example of what you are doing is below (causes the same error):

```js
let obj = {
true === true ? 'age : 22' : 'age :22 , name : "tom"'
}

console.log(obj);
```

You can try this with ternary operator like this:

```
const getMyHeader = (heading, advisorTags) => {
    if (advisorTags.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Typography
          variant="h6"
          component="h6"
          style={{ 'fontSize' : 16,
          'paddingTop' : (heading === 'White Advantages')  ? 0 : 10
          }} >
          {heading}
        </Typography>
      );
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  };
```

In the above code I am using an expression too, but only to assign a value to one of the keys of the particular object.

Comment: That is a very clever way of doing it and it worked perfectly, thank you. I am a bit confused why my code did not work.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it helps. Let me know

Comment: So in other words, assigning a value to an object is fine, it is just that you need the object there in the first place rather than an expression containing the object. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

style prop takes in a regular object, `'fontSize: 16, paddingTop: 10'` will not work, and this is most likely causes the bug.

You can try something like this

```
const getMyHeader = (heading, advisorTags) => {
  if (advisorTags.length > 0) {
    let style = { fontSize: 16 };
    if(heading === 'White Advantages') {
      style.paddingTop = 10;
    }
    return (
      <Typography
        variant="h6"
        component="h6"
        style={style}
      >
        {heading}
      </Typography>
    );
  } else {
    return '';
  }
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason why I can't have the ternary in the place it was in my code? I thought a ternary would leave in place just the text depending on the result of the condition?

Comment: @Jon You are correct about how the ternary works, however, your ternary returns an invalid object. This is what would the style props gets `style={{ 'fontSize: 16, paddingTop: 10' }}`, which is not acceptable for React.